# Button not working inside a div which has ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a div with ng-click
inside that div is a button, when i click the button the function bind with ng-click always execute but not the button, how to just execute the ng-click of button only

```
<div ng-click=redirectToPage()>
    ...
    <button><button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()` method to prevent the event from bubbling up.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Check demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/18a4p59b/5/)